# Short- vs. long arguments passed to mysqldump.exe

Tags: mysql

I have example command:

```
mysqldump.exe --user=ABCabc --password=ABCabc --host=ABCabc --port=ABCabc ABCabc> "D:\ABCabc.sql"
```

but I know same can be written as:

```
mysqldump -uABCabc -pABCabc -hABCabc -pABCabc ABCabc> "D:\ABCabc.sql"
```

First comand works but second give me error unknown host.
How can I fix it? 
Where I can learn about rules notation used in the windows comand line?

How to distinguish port to password?

Comment: *But I know same can be written as* - where do you know that from? why don't you just stick to the first variant since it works?

Comment: especially, I wonder, how it would distinguish -**p**assword from -**p**ort ...

Comment: I know, I have seen examples on stackoverflow, but without description

Comment: [see documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_user)

Comment: you have error in your second one - port is `-P` not `-p`

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer here. This has nothing to do with CMD (the standard Windows command shell). The syntax is set by the tool you call (here `mysqldump.exe`).

You should have a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) (as @Stephan pointed out in his comment).

Given your command line:

```
mysqldump.exe --user=ABCabc --password=ABCabc --host=ABCabc --port=ABCabc ABCabc
```

The proper usage of short options would be (note especially the upper case `P` as a shorthand option for `password`):

```
mysqldump.exe -u ABCabc -p ABCabc -h ABCabc -P ABCabc ABCabc
```

I elided the output redirection (`> D:\...`) because that is indeed the shell's (CMD) business and has in turn nothing to do with the specifics of `mysqldump.exe`.

Again, how did I know that? Not because there is a general pattern here [1], but simply because I read the documentation for the tool/application in question.

[1] Having that said, there are indeed *conventions* for command line arguments, here it looks like [GNU getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html), but it doesn't have to be that way for every application.

Comment: I was convinced that it is standardized, 
Standards for Command Line Interfaces
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html
http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces

Comment: Apart from the fact, that no one can _force the application to adhere to it_, it would be the decision of the application and not of the shell (CMD.exe, bash, ... or other) that invokes it. Also, standards are often platform agnostic, that is, on Windows (historically at least) GNU command line standards looked a little "alien".